# Files in Trash are not deleted in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, delete, trash

I have **probably** tried all the methods available on the internet including using trash-cleaner, other command prompts, and the direct clear trash from files. However, a large segment (more than 30GB) of trash just does not delete.

On running

```
myname@myname-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IKB:~$ trash-empty
```

I get a message of this kind:

```
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/files/wedding videos raw files
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/info/wedding videos raw files.trashinfo
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/files/wedding photos hd
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/info/wedding photos hd.trashinfo
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/files/System Volume Information
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/info/System Volume Information.trashinfo
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/files/Whatsapp Photos
trash-empty: cannot remove /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/info/Whatsapp Photos.trashinfo
```

Please suggest something that helps me solve this?

Comment: Your provided directory implies to me it's an external drive; is it mounted?

Comment: Alternatively, if you have sudo access, would you be able to just delete them manually? for example `sudo rm /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/files/wedding\ videos\ raw\ files`

Comment: @guiverc yes it external drive, and the trash files only show up while it is mounted.

Comment: @Smurfz I'll give it a try and update.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
sudo trash-empty
```

or try

```
sudo rm -rf /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/files/*
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf /media/jyotirmoy/Backup/.Trash-1000/info/*
```